# Laravel testing on demand notification

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a slack notification class that sends a message inside our company slack account, in a specific channel, every time an user performs the activation process.

The system works, but it's manually tested and that's not cool.

The notification is sent by a listener attached to an `UserHasBeenActivated` event, the listener is the following:

```
public function handle(UserHasBeenActivated $event)
{
    Notification::route("slack", config("services.slack.user.url"))
        ->notify(new UserActivated($event->user));
}
```

Pretty straight forward. The problem here is that the notification is on demand thus it's difficult to test... because there isn't any sort of documentation on how to test on demand notifications!

At the moment I'm stuck here:

```
public function it_sends_a_notification_when_an_user_is_activated()
{
    Notification::fake();

    $user = factory(User::class)->states("deleted")->create();
    $user->activate();

    Notification::assertSentTo(
        $user,
        UserActivated::class
    );
}
```

Of course this test fails, the `activate()` method is what triggers the Event `UserHasBeenActivated` and sequentially all the listeners, and one of them sends the corresponding notification.

Do you know how to test on demand Notifications? Is there any hidden API that am I missing?

Comment: A problem might be the difference in `UserActivated` and `UerHasBeenActivated`?

Comment: Nope sorry typo, edited

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta Unrelated question, but how did you manage to send a slack message this way? My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278174/laravel-5-5-on-demand-notification-with-slack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the newcomers**

Laravel introduces in `v5.5.14` the ability to test anonymous notification by using the provided `Notification::fake()` system.

More about this *new* feature here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21379