# Laravel 5.5 On demand notification with slack

Tags: laravel-5.5, slack

According to [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#on-demand-notifications), we can send a notification on demand without going through a model. How do I do the same using slack?

I want to do something like this:

```
$emailAddress = 'my email address';
Notification::route('mail', $emailAddress)
            ->route('slack', 'what do I put here?')
            ->notify(new TestNotification());
```

The code works without the `slack` line.

Edit: [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277323/laravel-testing-on-demand-notification) uses the on demand method

Comment: You most likely need a Laravel-Slack connector to make this work. Just google it and you get multiple github projects that provide that feature.

Comment: can you send a link

Answer (score 10):

You should you put the Slack Webhook URL. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#routing-slack-notifications

```
 Notification::route('slack', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/ZZZZ/YYYY/XXX')->notify(new DailyStats());
```