# How to test Laravel notification without notifiable?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

We are sending a slack message to our team channel hence not using a notifiable instance.
This is how I did it-

```
Notification::route('slack', env('SLACK_URL'))
    ->notify(new StaffNotification());
```

And in StaffNotification

```
public function toSlack() {
    return (new SlackMessage)->content('New Staff Message.');
}
```

How should I test StaffNotification as all the assert available are accepting the first parameter as notifiable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel testing on demand notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277323/laravel-testing-on-demand-notification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel creates an `AnonymousNotifiable` behind the scene when you have not a notifiable in your model, and you can use it:

```php
use Illuminate\Notifications\AnonymousNotifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class NotificationsTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSend()
    {
        Notification::fake();
        //perform your code
        Notification::assertSentTo(new AnonymousNotifiable(), StaffNotification::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has added a new assertion for these kind of use cases, called `assertSentOnDemand`, which you can use if you're not sending the notification to a notifiable class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class NotificationTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_notification_sent()
    {
        Notification::fake();

        // test notification
    
        Notification::assertSentOnDemand(StaffNotification::class);
    }
}
```